# AspNetCore 2.0 Create new MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm not able to create new aspnetcore 2 project using command line.

Below are steps and the error message i'm getting. Is there anyone who had the same problem like the one I'm getting ?

What was the fix. Thank you in advance.

- `dotnet new mvc`

> D:\Sample\tester\tester.csproj : error NU1202: Package
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.4.0 is not compatible with
>   netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0).
>   Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.4.0 supports:
>
> D:\Sample\tester\tester.csproj : error NU1202:   - net40
>   (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0) D:\Sample\tester\tester.csproj : error
>   NU1202:   - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>   D:\Sample\tester\tester.csproj : error NU1202:   - net46
>   (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6) D:\Sample\tester\tester.csproj : error
>   NU1202:   - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)

- `dotnet run`

> error NU1202: Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 2.1.1
>   is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0).
>   Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 2.1.1 supports:
>
> D:\Sample\tester\tester.csproj : error NU1202:   - net451
>   (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
>   D:\Sample\tester\tester.csproj :
>   error NU1202:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
>   D:\Sample\tester\tester.csproj : error NU1202: Package
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.4.0 is not compatible with
>   netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.4.0 supports:
>
> D:\Sample\tester\tester.csproj : error NU1202:   - net40
>   (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)\r D:\Sample\tester\tester.csproj : error
>   NU1202:   - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>
> D:\Sample\tester\tester.csproj : error NU1202:   - net46
>   (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6)
>   D:\Sample\tester\tester.csproj : error
>   NU1202:   - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
>   D:\Sample\tester\tester.csproj : error NU1202: Package
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector 2.4.1 is not
>   compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector 2.4.1 supports:
>
> D:\Sample\tester\tester.csproj : error NU1202:   - net40
>   (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
>   D:\Sample\tester\tester.csproj : error
>   NU1202:   - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>
> D:\Sample\tester\tester.csproj : error NU1202:   - netstandard1.6
>   (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)

**Note** :

I'm using: 
 -  Visual studio community 15.3.5.
 -  SDK netcore 2.0.0

Comment: There are someone mentioned about that compatible issue, you can refer once here: https://scottsauber.com/2017/08/22/fix-for-package-microsoft-aspnetcore-2-0-0-is-not-compatible-with-netcoreapp2-0/

Comment: Thank you Jacky, I don't have team city installed on my machine as per the link you sent me. Is this issue related to Nuget? If yes, can you please tell me what are the steps i need to follow to fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: Check you have NuGet 4.3 or higher installed. Install the lates sdk [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd)

Comment: Thank you Paolo, update Nuget fix the issue